# Insert value into class variable from main function

Tags: c++, class

This is the code i wrote to add two time objects, can anyone help?
I want that user should input time and it adds both time together.

Please tell me where i went wrong! please.

```
class time
{
    public: int hh,mm,ss;
};

int main()
{
    time t1;
    time t2;

    cout<<"Enter hour : "; 
    cin>>t1.hh;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter minutes : ";
    cin>>t1.mm;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter seconds : ";
    cin>>t1.ss;

    cout<<endl<<"Enter hour : ";
    cin>>t2.hh;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter minutes : ";
    cin>>t2.mm;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter seconds : ";
    cin>>t2.ss;

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<t1.hh<<":"<<t1.mm<<":"<<t1.ss;
    cout<<" + ";
    cout<<t2.hh<<":"<<t2.mm<<":"<<t2.ss;
    cout<<" = ";
    cout<<t1.hh+t2.hh<<":"<<t1.mm+t2.mm<<":"<<t1.ss+t2.ss;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling produces the following errors:

> main.cpp:13: error: expected `;' before 't1'
>
>   main.cpp:14: error: expected`;' before 't2'
>   main.cpp:17: error: 't1' was not declared in this scope
>   main.cpp:24: error: 't2' was not declared in this scope

Comment: What happens? Is the problem just that you didn't add an "endl" after the last output?

Comment: Sir, it gives me multiple error.

Comment: It has success fully compiled, thank you all and god bless this community and the helper's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have the following lines not shown:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
```

Change this line …

```
class t1;
class t2;
```

… to …

```
class time t1;
class time t2;
```

… and your program should compile.

Also, `getch` is a part of the `conio` library, which I don't have for some reason, so I'm used `getchar` instead:

```
getchar();
return 0;
```

Comment: @Mohsin Rookie mistake.  No problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you provide the error you're having.

However, you should certainly change

```
class t1;
class t2;
```

to

```
time t1;
time t2;
```

Moreover, you should avoid using the name `time` since it's a rather classic [function in c++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/). You could call your class `Time` to ensure a reader won't misunderstand your code.

Of course, you should change the declaration of `t1` and `t2` as well. It means you could try:

```
class Time
{
  public: int hh,mm,ss;
};

int main()
{
  Time t1;
  Time t2;
  [...]
```

Comment: After improving code it gives the following error.

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:12:10: error: expected ';' before 't1'
     time t1;
          ^
main.cpp:13:10: error: expected ';' before 't2'
     time t2;
          ^
main.cpp:16:10: error: 't1' was not declared in this scope
     cin>>t1.hh;
          ^
main.cpp:23:10: error: 't2' was not declared in this scope
     cin>>t2.hh;
          ^

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
int main()
{
    time t1;
    time t2;
```

Also you do not handle overflows when adding times (aka you can get more than 60 seconds):

```
time t3;
t3.hh = t1.hh + t2.hh;
t3.mm = t1.mm + t2.mm;
t3.ss = t1.ss + t2.ss;
if (t3.ss >= 60)
{
  t3.ss -= 60;
  t3.mm += 1;
}
if (t3.mm >= 60)
{
  t3.mm -= 60;
  t3.hh += 1;
}
cout << t3.hh << t3.mm << t3.ss << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you, i never thought of that!

Answer (score 0):

Assembled together by the tips above, this should compile and do the job:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Time
{
    public: int hh,mm,ss;
};

int main()
{
    Time t1;
    Time t2;

    cout<<"Enter hour : "; 
    cin>>t1.hh;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter minutes : ";
    cin>>t1.mm;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter seconds : ";
    cin>>t1.ss;

    cout<<endl<<"Enter hour : ";
    cin>>t2.hh;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter minutes : ";
    cin>>t2.mm;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter seconds : ";
    cin>>t2.ss;

    cout<<endl;
    cout<<t1.hh<<":"<<t1.mm<<":"<<t1.ss;
    cout<<" + ";
    cout<<t2.hh<<":"<<t2.mm<<":"<<t2.ss;
    cout<<" = ";
    cout<<t1.hh+t2.hh<<":"<<t1.mm+t2.mm<<":"<<t1.ss+t2.ss;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```